# How to make WP_Error message to appear under the password field?

Tags: css, wordpress, validation, woocommerce

I have just activated a password confirmation field in my Wordpress registration using this script

```
function registration_errors_validation($reg_errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email) {
    global $woocommerce;
    extract( $_POST );
    if ( strcmp( $password, $password2 ) !== 0 ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'registration-error', __( 'Passwords do not match. Please try again.', 'woocommerce' ) );      
    }
    return $reg_errors;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_errors', 'registration_errors_validation', 10,3);

// ----- add a confirm password fields match on the registration page
function wc_register_form_password_repeat() {
    ?>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_password2"><?php _e( 'Password Repeat', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password2" id="reg_password2" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['password2'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['password2'] ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'wc_register_form_password_repeat' );

// ----- Validate confirm password field match to the checkout page
function lit_woocommerce_confirm_password_validation( $posted ) {
    $checkout = WC()->checkout;
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ( $checkout->must_create_account || ! empty( $posted['createaccount'] ) ) ) {
        if ( strcmp( $posted['account_password'], $posted['account_confirm_password'] ) !== 0 ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Passwords do not match.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' ); 
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'lit_woocommerce_confirm_password_validation', 10, 2 );

// ----- Add a confirm password field to the checkout page
function lit_woocommerce_confirm_password_checkout( $checkout ) {
    if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) == 'no' ) {

        $fields = $checkout->get_checkout_fields();

        $fields['account']['account_confirm_password'] = array(
            'type'              => 'password',
            'label'             => __( 'Confirm password', 'woocommerce' ),
            'required'          => true,
            'placeholder'       => _x( 'Confirm Password', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce' )
        );

        $checkout->__set( 'checkout_fields', $fields );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_init', 'lit_woocommerce_confirm_password_checkout', 10, 1 );
```

My problem now is that the Error message (triggered by WP_Error) appears on the top of the page after refreshing it.
The behavior I would like to have is to have the error message appearing under the password field.

Any idea on how to achieve it?

Comment: At first I thought you were talking about wp-login.php From your code I understand it's about Woocommerce. Which page/screen are you talking about? Can't you just use CSS to position the error?

Comment: Any idea how? My CSS is basic

Comment: It will be hard to help you since I don't know the HTML of the screen. Also I don't know if there's already any CSS positioning the error message.

Comment: You would have to check where the message's container is located in the HTML. Is it underneath the password field? In that case there is CSS positioning it. Then you would have to look for a CSS property. Probably `position: absolute;` or `position: fixed;`. Then you need to override it with `position: relative` or `position: static;`